# vehicle trailer simulation in gazebo

Tags: gazebo, ros-noetic

I would like to create a vehicle with a trailer model in Gazebo. The hitch of the trailer is located at the center of the rear wheel axle of the vehicle, and I am using a revolute joint for the hitch. I have also installed two wheels on the trailer, with continuous wheel joints. Ideally, when the vehicle is moving forward and turning, the trajectory of the trailer should match the mathematical model of a tractor-trailer. However, what I observed in Gazebo is that the trailer becomes rigidly connected to the vehicle. When the vehicle moves forward and turns, the trailer wheels do not follow the motion, and the hitch joint seems to be rigid as well. Why is this happening? Is it not possible to achieve realistic trailer behavior in Gazebo?

Please help me understand why the trailer model in Gazebo is not exhibiting the expected behavior, where the trailer wheels should rotate and follow the vehicle's motion during forward and turning movements.

I may find the problem why the trailer is acting like it is rigidly connected with the chassis, this is because the incorrect setting of friction of model and their mass. Now, I try to reduce the mass of trailer and make it less than the one of chassis. Now it is moving like this. As shown in the gif, the movement of the trailer looks strange, as if it is fighting against the chassis. I think the friction, mass and the inertia of the link is not correct, but I don't know how to tune this kind of parameters, expecially for the friction "fdir" parameters.
[image]
**the full model has been updated on the github** [repo](https://github.com/Youhaochan/tractor_trailer/tree/master),
part of trailer description is as below

```
<link name="axle_link">
<visual>
  <origin xyz="0 0 ${tool_arm_length/2.0}" rpy="0 0 0" />
  <geometry>
    <cylinder radius="${tool_arm_radius}" length="${tool_arm_length}" />
  </geometry>
  <material name="blue" />
</visual>
<collision>
  <origin xyz="0 0 ${tool_arm_length/2.0}" rpy="0 0 0" />
  <geometry>
    <cylinder radius="${tool_arm_radius}" length="${tool_arm_length}" />
  </geometry>
</collision>
<xacro:cylinder_inertial mass="0.2" r="${tool_arm_radius}" l="${tool_arm_length}" />
```

```
<joint name="axle_link_to_chassis" type="revolute">
<axis xyz="1 0.0 0.0" rpy=" 0 0 0" />
<parent link="chassis_link" />
<child link="axle_link" />
<origin
  xyz="-${base_x_len/2.0} 0 -${base_z_len/2 + tool_arm_radius}"
  rpy="0 -${pi / 2.0} 0" />
<limit lower="-${pi/4.0}" upper="${pi/4.0}" effort="10.0" velocity="0.1"/>
```

```
<gazebo reference="axle_link">
<mu1 value="0.1" />
<mu2 value="0.1" />
<kp value="1000000.0" />
<kd value="10.0" />
<fdir1 value="1 0 0" />
<material>Gazebo/Grey</material>
```

```
<link name="trailer_link">
<visual>
  <geometry>
    <box size="${trailer_x_len} ${trailer_y_len} ${trailer_z_len} " />
  </geometry>
  <material name="green" />
</visual>
<collision>
  <geometry>
    <box size="${trailer_x_len} ${trailer_y_len} ${trailer_z_len} " />
  </geometry>
</collision>
<xacro:box_inertial mass="0.5" x="${trailer_x_len}" y="${trailer_y_len}" z="${trailer_z_len}" />
```

```
<joint name="trailer_link_to_axle" type="fixed">
<parent link="axle_link" />
<child link="trailer_link" />
<origin
  xyz=" ${tool_arm_radius + trailer_z_len/2} 0 ${trailer_x_len/2.0 + tool_arm_length}"
  rpy="0 ${pi/2.0} 0" />
```

```
<gazebo reference="trailer_left_wheel">
<mu1>0.1</mu1>
<mu2>0.1</mu2>
<kp>1000000.0</kp>
<kd>100.0</kd>
<minDepth>0.001</minDepth>
<maxVel>1.0</maxVel>
<material>Gazebo/FlatBlack</material>
```

```
  <link name="trailer_right_wheel">
<visual>
  <geometry>
    <box size="${wheel_radius * 2} ${wheel_radius * 2} ${wheel_radius * 2}" />
  </geometry>
  <material name="blue" />
</visual>
<collision>
  <geometry>
    <box size="${wheel_radius * 2} ${wheel_radius * 2} ${wheel_radius * 2}" />
  </geometry>
</collision>
<xacro:box_inertial mass="2" x="${wheel_radius * 2}" y="${wheel_radius * 2}" z="${wheel_radius * 2}" />
```

```
  <joint name="trailer_right_wheel_to_trailer_link" type="fixed">
<parent link="trailer_link" />
<child link="trailer_right_wheel" />
<origin
  xyz=" 0 ${trailer_y_len / 2.0 - wheel_radius} -${trailer_z_len/2.0 + wheel_radius}"
  rpy="0 0 0" />
```

```
  <gazebo reference="trailer_right_wheel">
<mu1>0.1</mu1>
<mu2>0.1</mu2>
<kp>1000000.0</kp>
<kd>100.0</kd>
<minDepth>0.001</minDepth>
<maxVel>1.0</maxVel>
<material>Gazebo/FlatBlack</material>
```

the model looks like this in rviz
[image: model]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and maybe add a photo and/or diagram so as to illustrate your problem..?

Comment: Your expectation of behavior seems reasonable. What you're asking for is help with your implementation, however you haven't shared any of that so it's impossible to do anything but guess at what you're doing. Please edit your question to add a description of what you're doing in a minimal example that shows your problem that you need help fixing.

Comment: Hi robot description has been added

Comment: Please don't screenshot text, but copy and paste the content into the file. Otherwise your code can't be easily searched and or manipulated or a suggestion changed. And an animation or at least diagram of the behaviors would be very helpful. 

It looks like you're calling what would usually be the trailer tongue the axle in your model. 

From what I see, I wonder what axis you have defined for your hitch joint. Is it going the direction that you want to have flexibility?